# Beginner question about a task in a course in C#

Tags: c#

The code

```
class Program
{
    static int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        x = 4;
        y = 3;
        int f = x + y;
        return f;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 4;
        int y = 3;
        Console.WriteLine("Answer: ");
        Add(x, y);
    }
}
```

Doing a beginner course in C# and I have been stuck at this question for two days now. 
I know its probably really simple, but I have tried so many different things that I think I have made it harder for me than it really.
I fixed to call strings in methods, but numbers seems hard.

The task is about to take two numbers in and that return the answer.
Tried searching around all the different errors I got with all the different tries, but didn't find the help, or the answers I understand.

Comment: don't you think sharing "all the different errors I got" would be helpful?

Answer (score 4):

You almost did all of it, just with 2 issues.

1. You should relay on the numbers you pass from `Main` to `Add` and not reassign the values inside `Add` otherwise passing them is useless and unusable for other numbers.
2. `Add` returns a value but you never save it + print it.

Example for #1

```
static int Add(int x, int y)
{
    int f = x + y;
    return f;
}
```

Example of #2

```
var result = Add(x, y);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an working version with explaination:

```
class Program
{
    static int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        //x = 4; these are passed in as parameter, no need to set it
        //y = 3;
        int f = x + y;
        return f;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int someX = 4; //these are only known inside the scope of "Main"
        int someY = 3;

        int result = Add(someX, someY); //these are passed inside the function, 
                                        //the value is copied

         Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Corrected Example:**

```
class Program
{ 
    static int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        // You don't need to redefine the variables x and y,
        // because you get them when you call the method

        // You can shorten the last part
        // and just return the Addition
        return x + y;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 4;
        int y = 3;
        // Prints the Word Answer
        // as well as the Addition result into the Console now
        Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + Add(x, y));
    }
}
```

**Your Errors:**

1. You never printed the Result into the Console!
2. You shouldn't redefine the variables in the Function, because if you do that you don't need to use a function in the first place
3. You can shorten the return statement (you don't have to)
4. You can add Add(x,y) into the Console.WriteLine because it returns a Integer, therefore it is basically like writting `Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + 7);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even easier and simple 
 In addition , this answer is more dynamic as you can choose the two numbers every time you run the program:

```
class Program
{
    static int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return  x + y;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), 
                                           Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())).ToString());
        Console.ReadLine(); //In order to be able to see the result in the screen
        
    }
}
```